# Bad access code 1 glDrawElements

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to draw things each frame by batching it. This means I have to use `glBufferSubData()`, which I'm unfamiliar with. I'm thinking I'm doing something wrong when substituting the data, causing the access violation when calling `glDrawElements`.

My setup code:

```
GL_TRY(glGenVertexArrays(1, &mVao));
GL_TRY(glBindVertexArray(mVao));

GL_TRY(glGenBuffers(1, &mEbo));
GL_TRY(glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mEbo));
GL_TRY(glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, NULL, GL_STREAM_DRAW));

GL_TRY(glGenBuffers(1, &mVbo));
GL_TRY(glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mVbo));
GL_TRY(glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, NULL, GL_STREAM_DRAW));

GLint posAttrib;
GL_TRY(posAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(mShader.getProgram(), "position"));
GL_TRY(glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib));
GL_TRY(glVertexAttribPointer(posAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(float), 0));

GLint texAttrib;
GL_TRY(texAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(mShader.getProgram(), "texCoords"));
GL_TRY(glEnableVertexAttribArray(texAttrib));
GL_TRY(glVertexAttribPointer(texAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(float), (void*)(2 * sizeof(float))));

GL_TRY(glBindVertexArray(0));
```

My drawing code:

```
GL_TRY(glBindVertexArray(mVao));

GL_TRY(glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mEbo));
GL_TRY(glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, NULL, GL_STREAM_DRAW));
GL_TRY(glBufferSubData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, indices.size() * sizeof(GLuint), &indices[0]));

GL_TRY(glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mVbo));
GL_TRY(glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, NULL, GL_STREAM_DRAW));
GL_TRY(glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, vertices.size() * sizeof(Vertex), &vertices[0]));

GL_TRY(glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, (GLsizei)indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0));

GL_TRY(glBindVertexArray(0));
```

I've been checking everything and trying to debug for a while now, but I just can't find what I'm doing wrong.

For the record, `GL_TRY` is a macro that reports any OpenGL errors. I'm not getting any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of your buffers is always 0:

```
GL_TRY(glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, NULL, GL_STREAM_DRAW));
GL_TRY(glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, vertices.size() * sizeof(Vertex), &vertices[0]));
```

The second argument to `glBufferData()` specifies the size of the buffer, which is 0 in your case.

As the name suggests, `glBufferSubData()` can only replace sub-sections of the buffer. It can't change the size. So the size is still 0 after this call. You should actually get a `GL_INVALID_VALUE` error from this call.

One way of looking at these entry points is:

- `glBufferData()` allocates buffer memory, and optionally fills it with data. When called with `NULL` as the data pointer, the comparable call for CPU memory is `malloc()`.
- `glBufferSubData()` writes data to already allocated buffer memory. It does not change the amount of memory allocated. The comparable call for CPU memory is `memcpy()`.

To make this work, you'll need to pass the size to `glBufferData()`:

```
GL_TRY(glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(Vertex), NULL, GL_STREAM_DRAW));
GL_TRY(glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, vertices.size() * sizeof(Vertex), &vertices[0]));
```

Using `glBufferSubData()` does not really make much sense in this case. You might just as well pass the data to `glBufferData()` here. `glBufferSubData()` is primarily useful if you want to replace only part of your buffer.

To use `glBufferSubData()` in your case, you'll want to call `glBufferData()` only once, during setup. This will work well as long as the size is constant, or you can at least establish a good upper limit. Otherwise you will have to call it again when the size changes. But if you want to use `glBufferSubData()` productively, this would still have to be much less frequent than every draw call. Otherwise you're better off specifying the data as part of the `glBufferData()` call:

```
GL_TRY(glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
                    vertices.size() * sizeof(Vertex), &vertices[0]), GL_STREAM_DRAW));
```

Comment: Right now I'm no longer using `glBufferSubData()`. I am still using `glBufferData()` each frame. So I just replace the entire buffer (which is what I want). Is this the best way to do this?